# Why brackets can't be installed on Debian?

Tags: system-installation

```
 sudo  dpkg -i Bracket*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brackets.
(Reading database ... 85361 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Brackets.Release.1.8.64-bit.deb ...
Unpacking brackets (1.8.0-17108) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brackets:
 brackets depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package brackets (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brackets
```

Now to install `libgcrypt20`.

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt20
```

To install `brackets` again.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  brackets
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 143 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 170 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 88821 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing brackets (1.8.0-17108) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
```

Can't install it ,how to fix ?

```
debian8@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install  libgcrypt11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgcrypt11 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgcrypt11' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You installed a different package than it asked for.

Comment: Package 'libgcrypt11' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install `libgcrypt11` download the `.deb` file from [here](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/snapshot/Debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/) and install it:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gdebi
wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/snapshot/Debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5_amd64.deb
gdebi libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5_amd64.deb
```

Download Barckets from [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases)

```
wget https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/download/release-1.6/Brackets.Release.1.6.64-bit.deb
gdebi Brackets.Release.1.6.64-bit.deb
$brackets
```